# Why Status bar is appearing with shadow?

Tags: android, statusbar

Status bar of my app is not seem as clear or it appears with some shadow.

This is how my status bar looks:

[image]

And it should appear like this:

[image]

Why it isn't looking like this?

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>\

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

What's wrong with this? Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this line

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

from your values-v21/styles.xml

Comment: Pleasure! It;s been annoying me as well... this is the simplest solution that won't affect the compat layout. You can mark as answered

Answer (score 0):

If you are in android 5 or later you can set the elevation of the actionbar to 0 by below code

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

If not 5 or higher then add below style in your theme

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```